# OpenCV 3 build problems at 37%?

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to build Opencv 3 and openCV contrib from source - I followed this tutorial

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

I successfully configured but when I try make it I get an error at 37% :(

```
(cv) pturner@pturner-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/workspace/OpenCV/openc
v/build$ make -j4        
[  0%] Built target opencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp
[  1%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  1%] Built target opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp
[  1%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp
[  1%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_core
[  3%] Built target libwebp
[  3%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_core
[  5%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_test_flann_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_flann_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_test_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_perf_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_test_ml_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_ml_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_photo_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_test_photo_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_reg_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_perf_photo_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_surface_matching_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_test_reg_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_perf_reg_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_video_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_test_viz_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_test_video_pch_dephelp
[  5%] Built target opencv_perf_video_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Built target opencv_viz_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Built target opencv_dnn_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Built target opencv_test_dnn_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Built target opencv_fuzzy_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Built target opencv_test_fuzzy_pch_dephelp
[  7%] Built target libprotobuf
[  7%] Built target opencv_perf_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp
[  7%] Built target opencv_test_shape_pch_dephelp
[  7%] Built target opencv_shape_pch_dephelp
[  8%] Built target opencv_test_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp
[  8%] Built target opencv_test_videoio_pch_dephelp
[  8%] Built target opencv_perf_videoio_pch_dephelp
[  8%] Built target opencv_perf_objdetect_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_test_highgui_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_test_objdetect_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_plot_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_superres_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_test_superres_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_perf_superres_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_xobjdetect_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_perf_xphoto_pch_dephelp
[ 10%] Built target opencv_test_xphoto_pch_dephelp
[ 11%] Built target opencv_bgsegm_pch_dephelp
[ 11%] Built target opencv_test_bgsegm_pch_dephelp
[ 14%] Built target opencv_perf_bioinspired_pch_dephelp
[ 14%] Built target opencv_bioinspired_pch_dephelp
[ 14%] Built target opencv_test_bioinspired_pch_dephelp
[ 14%] Built target opencv_dpm_pch_dephelp
[ 14%] Built target opencv_face_pch_dephelp
[ 14%] Built target opencv_features2d_pch_dephelp
[ 15%] Built target opencv_test_features2d_pch_dephelp
[ 16%] Built target opencv_perf_features2d_pch_dephelp
[ 16%] Built target opencv_test_line_descriptor_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_perf_line_descriptor_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_line_descriptor_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_saliency_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_text_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_test_calib3d_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_test_rgbd_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_ccalib_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_perf_calib3d_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_rgbd_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_test_stereo_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_stereo_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_perf_stereo_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_structured_light_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_test_structured_light_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_test_tracking_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_tracking_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target opencv_perf_tracking_pch_dephelp
[ 19%] Built target opencv_perf_xfeatures2d_pch_dephelp
[ 19%] Built target opencv_videostab_pch_dephelp
[ 19%] Built target opencv_test_xfeatures2d_pch_dephelp
[ 19%] Built target opencv_xfeatures2d_pch_dephelp
[ 19%] Built target opencv_perf_ximgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target opencv_test_ximgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target opencv_ximgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target opencv_aruco_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target opencv_test_aruco_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target opencv_optflow_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target opencv_test_optflow_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target numeric
[ 21%] Built target opencv_test_sfm_pch_dephelp
[ 21%] Built target opencv_sfm_pch_dephelp
[ 21%] Built target opencv_test_stitching_pch_dephelp
[ 21%] Built target opencv_stitching_pch_dephelp
[ 21%] Built target opencv_perf_stitching_pch_dephelp
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgcodecs
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videoio
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_flann
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_flann
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_imgproc
[ 21%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_imgproc
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ml
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_ml
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_photo
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_photo
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_photo
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_reg
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_reg
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_reg
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_video
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_surface_matching
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_video
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_video
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_viz
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_viz
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_dnn
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_fuzzy
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_dnn
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_imgcodecs
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_fuzzy
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_imgcodecs
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_shape
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_shape
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_videoio
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_videoio
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_highgui
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_objdetect
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_objdetect
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_objdetect
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_plot
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_superres
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_superres
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_superres
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_xobjdetect
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_xphoto
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_xphoto
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_bgsegm
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_bgsegm
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_bioinspired
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_bioinspired
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_bioinspired
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_dpm
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_face
[ 23%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_features2d
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_line_descriptor
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_features2d
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_features2d
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_line_descriptor
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_line_descriptor
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_saliency
[ 24%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_text
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_calib3d
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_calib3d
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ccalib
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_calib3d
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_rgbd
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_stereo
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_stereo
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_rgbd
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_structured_light
[ 25%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stereo
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_tracking
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_structured_light
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_tracking
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_tracking
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_xfeatures2d
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videostab
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_xfeatures2d
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_xfeatures2d
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_ximgproc
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_ximgproc
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ximgproc
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_aruco
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_aruco
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_optflow
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_optflow
[ 28%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_sfm
[ 29%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_stitching
[ 29%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_sfm
[ 29%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_stitching
[ 30%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stitching
[ 32%] Built target multiview
[ 32%] Built target correspondence
[ 32%] Building CXX object modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/simple_pipeline/CMakeFiles/simple_pipeline.dir/tracks.cc.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/simple_pipeline/CMakeFiles/simple_pipeline.dir/bundle.cc.o
[ 34%] Built target opencv_core
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_flann
[ 34%] Building CXX object modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann.dir/src/miniflann.cpp.o
[ 37%] Built target opencv_imgproc
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_ml
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/gbt.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/data.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/rtrees.cpp.o
/home/pturner/workspace/OpenCV/opencv/build/opencv_contrib/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/simple_pipeline/bundle.cc: In function 'void libmv::{anonymous}::EuclideanBundlePointsOnly(libmv::DistortionModelType, const libmv::vector<libmv::Marker>&, libmv::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 1> >&, double*, libmv::EuclideanReconstruction*)':
/home/pturner/workspace/OpenCV/opencv/build/opencv_contrib/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/simple_pipeline/bundle.cc:427:11: error: 'struct ceres::Solver::Options' has no member named 'use_explicit_schur_complement'
   options.use_explicit_schur_complement = true;
           ^
/home/pturner/workspace/OpenCV/opencv/build/opencv_contrib/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/simple_pipeline/bundle.cc: In function 'void libmv::EuclideanBundleCommonIntrinsics(const libmv::Tracks&, int, int, libmv::EuclideanReconstruction*, libmv::CameraIntrinsics*, libmv::BundleEvaluation*)':
/home/pturner/workspace/OpenCV/opencv/build/opencv_contrib/modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/simple_pipeline/bundle.cc:597:11: error: 'struct ceres::Solver::Options' has no member named 'use_explicit_schur_complement'
   options.use_explicit_schur_complement = true;
           ^
make[2]: *** [modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/simple_pipeline/CMakeFiles/simple_pipeline.dir/bundle.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/sfm/src/libmv_light/libmv/simple_pipeline/CMakeFiles/simple_pipeline.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/ann_mlp.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/lr.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/testset.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/inner_functions.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/tree.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/em.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/svm.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/knearest.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/kdtree.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/nbayes.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/ml/CMakeFiles/opencv_ml.dir/src/boost.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann.dir/src/flann.cpp.o
[ 37%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_ml.so
[ 37%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 37%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_flann.so
[ 37%] Built target opencv_flann
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I managed to get further in the compilation by omitting `-j4`, but I still get the same error 84% through the compilation. Have you had any luck since posting this?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `CC = gcc` and `CXX = g++`